# Use embeded firebird database with SSIS for ETL process

Tags: ssis, firebird, etl

I don't have too many experience with SSIS, and I would like some suggestions / advices.

I need to implement a SSIS package for ETL, for migrationg firebird database to Sql Server.

For source  I have direct access to Firebird database (GDB) and I don't want to use the firebird server, but instead somehow access the GDB directly, maybe with the help of the firebird embedded server (the DLL)

For destination, I prefer to use as destination the endpoints of WCF services, if possible, but I can save to destination database as well if no other option.

Does anyone have some experience with those and can give some suggestions / directions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create the data connection using ODBC driver for FireBird - it asks for location of client dll, which should be the fbembedd.dll / gds32.dll, and then you can see the data